# Start multiple spiders sequentially from another spider

Tags: scrapy

I have one spider which creates +100 spiders with arguments.
Those spiders scrape x items and forward them to a mysqlpipeline.
The mysqldatabase can handle 10 connections at the time.
Due to that reason I can only have max 10 spiders running at the same time.
How can I make this happen?

My not succesful approach now is
- Add spiders to a list in the first spider like this:

```
if item.get('location_selectors') is not None and item.get('start_date_selectors') is not None:
        spider = WikiSpider.WikiSpider(template=item.get('category'), view_threshold=0, selectors = {
                                'location': [item.get('location_selectors')],
                                'date_start': [item.get('start_date_selectors')],
                                'date_end': [item.get('end_date_selectors')]
                         })
        self.spiders.append(spider)
```

Then in the first spider I listen to the close_spider signal:

```
def spider_closed(self, spider):
   for spider in self.spiders:
        process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
        process.crawl(spider)
```

But this approach gives me the following error:
connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion

What is the correct way to start multiple spiders in a sequentially manner?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you also reading from the database? or it is just about writing the items you get?

Comment: just writing to the database

Comment: and what about just calling one of the `spiders` and passing the remaining ones to the next one? and so on so every spider handles the remaining spiders until it is empty.